# Sum within a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sum, inner-join

I am not getting my head around this, and wondered if anyone may be able to help me with this.

`TLB_UKKEL` contains climate records

```
Date    | TGem | TEqui 
1/1/2016, 10.1 , 9.3 
2/1/2016, 11.3 , 9.8 
3/1/2016, 15.3 , X
...
```

The `TEqui` is the sum of: (`0.6*TGem + 0.3* TGem from de day before + 0.1 * TGem from two day's before`).

The day before can I call back with `INNER JOIN`. But how can I do the sum of them?

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Comment: what happen if you dont have previous day?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it's for an ms Access database.

Comment: `@Juan Carlos Oropeza` only the first 2 have no previous day's, the other 3000 records are in row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LEFT JOINS like this:

```
SELECT t.Date,T.TGem,
       (T.TGEM*0.6)+(coalesce(S.TGem,0)*0.3)+(coalesce(F.TGem,0)*0.1) as TEqui
FROM TLB_UKKEL t
LEFT OUTER JOIN TLB_UKKEL s ON(t.date = s.date+1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TLB_UKKEL f ON(t.date = f.date+2)
```

You didn't specify your DBMS, so I used coalesce.. not all DBMS supports that so you may have to change it to NVL or isnull or something.

If previous or 2 days ago doesn't exists, it will sum this day as 0 .(Again.. don't know if thats what you want since you explanations is missing some details)

Comment: It's in a ACCESS database. Just a regular local database. Only the first 2 dates doesn't exists. so i may result there as a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,

I have tried it. But it doesn't work.

If i do:

`SELECT t.Datum,T.TGem,
            (T.TGem*0.6)+(F.TGem * 0.4) as QR_Tequi
FROM Gegevens1 t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Gegevens1 f ON (t.Datum = f.Datum+1)`

if i use the code above everything works perfectly. If I use a second LEFT OUTER JOIN I get a Syntax Error 3075.